# Showing statistics for mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table. It contains the folowing columns:

Cathegory | Priority |

Is there a finished script or a way to display statistics for these columns?

Basically what I am trying to do is show statistics for these columns.

For example,

> cathegory can have different values, as an example: (Continent,
>   Country, City, Street).
>   Priority can contain a value between 1-10.

So I would need to display how many rows there are, the and the different values for each row.

For example:

```
4 of the priority 8 rows have 'continent' as catheogry,
43 of the priority 8 rows have 'country' as cathegory,
329 of the priority 8 rows have 'city' as cathegory
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(*), " of the priority 8 rows have 'continent' as category.") FROM \`table\` WHERE \`category\` = "continent" AND \`priority\` = 8;`

Comment: You said 'Priority can contain a value between 1-10'
but in you desired output result you put 43 for 'priority' can you please clarify ?
**43 of the priority 8 rows have 'country' as cathegory**

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in scripts that can do that for you but certainly you get all that kind of information using SQL, that's the basic idea of a relational database.

Number of rows in table

```
select count(*) from table;
```

The example

```
select cathegory, count(cathegory) nbr_of_cathegories_for_prio_8 from table where priority = 8 group by cathegory;
```

Comment: btw, it's spelled category, not cathegory :)

Answer (score 0):

In you example :  `329 of the priority 8 rows have 'city' as cathegory`

I assume that:

> 8 - is the priority value.
>     329 - how many time the priority is repeated for that specific priority for a specific category.

the PHP implimentation will look something like:

```
<?php

$sql = "
       SELECT Priority, COUNT(Priority) as nbr_of_Priorities, cathegory, 
       FROM table_Name
       GROUP BY Priority, cathegory
    ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
         echo $row['nbr_of_Priorities'].'of the priority'.$row[' Priority'];
         echo 'has'.$row['cathegory'].'as catheogry';
}
?>
```